# ABP - How does abp.auth being evaluated when starting a project?

Tags: asp.net-boilerplate

I added a side-bar menu and maybe twisted a little, somehow the abp.auth isn't working anymore.

I checked the abp.js, all I found is

```
abp.auth = abp.auth || {};
abp.auth.allPermissions = abp.auth.allPermissions || {};
```

So where does abp.auth or abp get the value in the first place?
I checked the role application service, no breakpoint is entered.
Then how can I trace this? Is it done inside the ABP framework? If so , how can I debug the abp.dll or whatever abp.XXX.dll in the template?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abp.auth` is initialized in [~/lib/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/17e3086b2386c7fb2561bbeaf2096cc89abfcb26/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/wwwroot/lib/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js).

That's included in [_Layout.cshtml](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/bfb6060de3133a87c13fc4dac07ec3f5c04e9e98/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L166)
 by default:

```xml
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/abp.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/view-resources/Views/_Bundles/shared-layout.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

Since it's a JavaScript library and not a **.dll**, it can be updated in [package.json](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/907a1ef7ecd74f1ca47e826af05cd6f8ea597afe/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/wwwroot/package.json) using **yarn**/**npm**.

> abp = abp || {}. So where does the abp at the right come from?

It doesn't necessarily come from anywhere. It's done like this so that you can define `abp` and add your properties to the object even before **abp.js** loads, and this avoids replacing it.

> Where does abp.auth get its value then?

`abp.auth` is just a JavaScript object. If you mean the `allPermissions` property, see [#2569](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2569).
It's populated in `AuthorizationScriptManager`.

> how to debug this library?

To enable debugging, change Visual Studio (2017+) Debugging options like in the [docs](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Debugging):

- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"
- Check "Enable source server support"
- Check "Enable source link support"

Answer (score 0):

abp.auth is being set after successful login. It makes GET request to *http://mywebsite.com/AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll*

The result of [AbpUserConfiguration](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/92597962f2240b14dc2d67ac3e5ac73ddd95163e/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Controllers/AbpUserConfigurationController.cs#L16)/GetAll action is [AbpUserConfigurationDto](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/92597962f2240b14dc2d67ac3e5ac73ddd95163e/src/Abp.Web.Common/Web/Models/AbpUserConfiguration/AbpUserConfigurationDto.cs#L13). 
There's **Auth** property in this result.

Search your solution for GetAll. You can find the client-side code.